# How to Enhance this finger print?

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to extract finger print from this image by using green LED backlight but when it convert to binarize image most of finger print is gone.

```
gray= green
```

I use this fomular to convert from this color image

[image: Color Image]

to this gray image

[image: Gray Image]

I use otsu for binarization. So Which preprocessing I should use before convert to binarization to emphasis the finger print.

[image: Binarized Image]

Comment: you could just upload to imgur.com and link to that image from here, we'll happily include the link for you :) (oh by the way, I don't think the green and grey are exactly the same image)

Comment: I'm no image processing expert, but I remember Otsu's method being very cluster-oriented. Have you tried other methods, and if so, which?

Comment: @MarcusMüller http://imgur.com/a/FlTRR

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Thank you for your respond :)

I know only otsu. Do you have another methods name? I use python+opencv.

Comment: These are three different finger print pictures. Could you please take **one** and post green, grey and binarized? Not doing that makes this more guesswork than it needs to be.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sure. A second

Comment: @MarcusMüller Done. Please check it out.

Comment: Playing a bit around with ImageJ, your image is not uniformly enlightened. Hence, you cannot use a global threshold, such as Otsu's method. You can have a try with local/adaptive thresholding the gray image. See e.g. http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/adpthrsh.htm or http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/what-are-the-most-common-algorithms-for-adaptive-thresholding

Comment: Also, you can have a look at scale-space methods, such as http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6065496 or http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Handouts/Lectures/2014_Spring/Combined_Slides/13-Scale-Space-Combined.pdf

Comment: yeah, I think you might need to go much more for edge-based approaches. Notice how the background is brighter than the fingerprint on the left of the print, but darker on the right? That's a pretty unfortunate setting, because you can't even say that within a small local patch the fingerprint is the lighter/darker part. If you can change something about the way these photos are made, I'd definitely try to enhance the evenness of background irradiation

Answer (score 2):

Two steps,

1. do a simple histogram equalization to make the brightness a little
   bit more even.
2. Then use canny edge detector (as suggested by Marcus Muller).

matlab code:

```
I=imread('Your Image');
G1=rgb2gray(I);
G2=histeq(G1);
E2=edge(G2,'canny'); 
figure imshow(E2,[]);
```

Result (I hope it is what your are looking for):

[image]